# Can it be proven that infinite many primes can be formed only using two distinct digits?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, decimal-expansion

It seems obvious that infinite many primes can be formed only using two distinct digits.

$67776767776667777777$ is an example for such a prime. Even if we allow only the digits $0$ and $1$, there are $2^{n-2}$ numbers with $n$ digits, for which the first and last digit is $1$. So, we can expect that some of those numbers are prime for every sufficiently large number $n$.

> Can it be proven that infinite many primes contain only two distinct digits in the decimal representation ?

Comment: Similar questioh at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162042/infinitely-many-prime-numbers-with-prescribed-digits?rq=1, which is answered by GerryMyerson: the status is not known.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this very negative result.

Comment: I recommend you set up an Internet alert on this page: http://oeis.org/A020469