# Twice prime number?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

A twice prime number is defined as a prime number whose digits are also prime. For example: $23$ is prime. It is made up of the digit $2$, which is prime, and the digit $3$, which is also prime. Therefore, $23$ is twice prime. Counter example: $19$ is prime, but $1$ nor $9$ is prime and therefore $19$ is not twice prime.

Does twice prime only consist of two prime digits? Or can we have a three digit prime which can qualify as twice prime?

Comment: $113,137,173$ are some of them

Comment: Next questions: are there infinitely many twice primes? And also, does this concept already exist under a different guise? Finally, I feel uncomfortable that this is a concept rooted in our decimal number system.

Comment: @user35508 $1$ is not considered a prime number- I believe that's what is alluded to above.

Comment: @ColmBhandal ... It is also made up like $11$ and $3$

Comment: @user35508 Very good point. But my interpretation of the OPs question is that "digit" means single decimal digit. We must await clarification from the OP...?

Comment: @ColmBhandal Proving that there are infinitely many primes with prescribed digits in a given set $S$ is an open question (except some trivial cases; you may remember, for instance, the case $S=\{1\}$).

Comment: See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162042/infinitely-many-prime-numbers-with-prescribed-digits

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti Thanks for the link! Also, I take it then we want to show that there are infinitely many primes with digits in $\{2, 3, 5, 7\}$

Comment: See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit for the case of primes with only digit 1 (note that, in base 2, it corresponds to Mersenne primes)

Comment: We have rather famous three-digit example, following Gauss we can now construct a regular $257$-gon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
233, 257, 2377, 23327,\ldots.
$$