# Proof that $n!$ is divisible by $(n+1)^2$ for $n=xy+x+y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, factorial

I noticed the other day that for $n>8, n\in\mathbb{N}$, the factorial $n!$ seems to be divisible by $(n+1)^2$ when $n$ can be written in the form $xy+x+y$ (where $x,y\geq1$ and $\in\mathbb{N}$). Some examples:

- $n=14=2 \times 4+2+4$ (i.e. $x=2$, $y=4$), and we have $14!|15^2$
- $n=15=3 \times 3+3+3$ (i.e. $x=y=3$), and we have $15!|16^2$,
- $n=19=3 \times 4+3+4$ (i.e. $x=3$, $y=4$), and we have $19!|20^2$,
- ...

This seems to hold for the first $15$ values I checked, so it seemed natural to try to prove it for all $n=xy+x+y$, however I could not find a proof. Here is my attempt:

Plugging $xy+x+y$ into the expressions above and noticing that $xy+x+y+1=(x+1)(y+1)$, we need to prove that

$$
(xy+x+y)!|(x+1)^2(y+1)^2,
$$

or

$$
\Gamma((x+1)(y+1))|(x+1)^2(y+1)^2.
$$

It is easy to prove that

$$
\Gamma((x+1)(y+1))|(x+1)(y+1)
$$

however I am struggling to prove the same for $(x+1)^2(y+1)^2$. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wlog. $x\le y$.
If we are lucky, we find $x+1,2(x+1),y+1,2(y+1)$ as different elements among the factors $1,2,3,\ldots, n$ and we are done.

How can we fail to be lucky? The four candidates may be too large or not be different after all. As we assume $x\le y$, the following list is exhaustive:

- It may happen that $2(y+1)>n=xy+x+y$. This implies $x=1$. And indeed, $x=1$, $y=2$ gives $n=5$ and $36$ does not divide $5!$. More generally if $y+1$ is prime, then $(2y+1)!$ is not divisible by $(y+1)^2$.
- It may happen that $x+1=y+1$, which of course means that $x=y$. If $x\le 3$, we have $n\le 8$, which is excluded. If $x\ge 4$,  we can use the factors $x+1,2(x+1),3(x+1),4(x+1)$ instead. These are guaranteed to be different and we have $4(x+1)\le xy+y<n$.
- It may happen that $2(x+1)=y+1$. Then we can use $x+1,2(x+1)=y+1, 3(x+1), 2(y+1)$ instead.

Thus

> If $n=xy+x+y>8$ with positive integers $x,y$ then $(n+1)^2\mid n!$ except when $n+1$ is twice a prime.

Comment: This shows it is divisible by $n+1$

Comment: @Michael Working on it. Problem is that the claim is false in general.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I don't see how "twice a prime" comes into the equation here... Could you please explain more?

Comment: @Pickle The exception is mentioned in the first bullet point when $n=2y+1$ and $y+1$ is prime, so $n+1$ is twice the prime $y+1$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen So you don't actually mean this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2335726/twice-prime-number

Answer (score -1):

$\color{Green}{\text{Question}}$ : 
Find all integers $n$; 
such that $\color{Green}{(n+1)! \mid n!} $ .

---

---

$\color{Blue}{\star \ \ \ \ \text{condition}}$ :

Now suppose that $n+1$ can be written 
in the form $n+1=ab$; 
with $2 < a,b$. 
Also assume that one of the following occures:

- If $a= b$; then $5 \leq a=b$.
- If $a=2b$; then $5 \leq b  $.
- If $2a=b$; then $5 \leq a  $.

---

With the condition as in 
$\color{Blue}{\star}$ ; 
we claim that 
the assertion is $\color{Blue}{\text{true}}.$

---

Let $n, a, b$ to be fixed as above in $\color{Blue}{\star}$ . 
Notice that if we let $x:=a-1$ and $y:=b-1$ 
then one can easilly see that: 
$$n=xy+x+y.$$

---

---

$\color{Blue}{\text{Remark(I)}}$ : 
With the notation as in $\color{Blue}{\star}$;

- If $a=b$ , with $5 \leq a$ 
  then we have: 
  $$b < 2b < 3b < 4b < ab=n+1 \Longrightarrow b < 2b < 3b <4b \leq n=ab-1 \ ; $$ 
  so we can conclede that: 
  $$(b)(2b)(3b)(4b)=24(ab)^2=24(n+1)^2 \mid n! ;$$ 
  which implies that: $(n+1)^2 \mid n! \ \ $ .

---

- If $a=2b$ ;  with $5 \leq b$ 
  then we have: 
  $$b < 2b < 3b < 4b < ab=n+1 \Longrightarrow b < 2b < 3b <4b \leq n=ab-1 \ ; $$ 
  so we can conclede that: 
  $$(b)(2b)(3b)(4b)=6(ab)^2=6(n+1)^2 \mid n! ;$$ 
  which implies that: $(n+1)^2 \mid n! \ \ $ .

---

- If $2a=b$ ;  with $5 \leq a$ 
  then we have: 
  $$a < 2a < 3a < 4a < ba=n+1 \Longrightarrow a < 2a < 3a <4a \leq n=ba-1 \ ; $$ 
  so we can conclede that: 
  $$(a)(2a)(3a)(4a)=6(ab)^2=6(n+1)^2 \mid n! ;$$ 
  which implies that: $(n+1)^2 \mid n! \ \ $ .

---

- If $a \neq b$ and $a \neq 2b$ and $2a \neq b$ ; 
  then we have: 
  $$b < 2b < ab=n+1 \Longrightarrow b < 2b \leq n=ab-1 \ ; $$ 
  $$a < 2a < ab=n+1 \Longrightarrow a < 2a \leq n=ab-1 \ ; $$
  so we can conclede that: 
  $$(b)(2b)(a)(2a)=4(ab)^2=4(n+1)^2 \mid n! ;$$ 
  which implies that: $(n+1)^2 \mid n! \ \ $ .

---

---

---

---

---

---

**Remark(II)**: Integer $N$ 
can not be written 
in the form $N=ab$; 
with $2 < a,b$; 
if and only if 
$N$ is prime or twice a prime.

---

**Remark(III)**: 
We can split the integres in three cases:

1. $\color{Red}{   n+1 =   \text{prime numbers and twice of prime numbers; 
   for which the assertion is wrong!}   }.$
2. $\color{Purple}{ n+1= a.a 
    \ \ \ 
   \text{for}    
   \ \ \ 
   a \in \{ 1, 2, 3, 4 \} }.$ 
   This case has only four numbers; 
   which can you check out that 
   the assertion is $\color{Blue}{\text{true}}$ only for 
   $\color{Blue}{n+1=16}$ and 
   $\color{Blue}{n+1= 1}$ .
3. $\color{Purple}{ n+1= a.(2a) 
    \ \ \ 
   \text{for}    
   \ \ \ 
   a \in \{ 1, 2, 3, 4 \} }.$ 
   This case has only four numbers; 
   which can you check out that 
   the assertion is $\color{Blue}{\text{true}}$ only for 
   $\color{Blue}{n+1=18}$ and 
   $\color{Blue}{n+1=32}$ .

---

$\color{Green}{\text{Remark(IV)}}$ : 
Except for the following cases; 
for which the assertion is 
$\color{Red}{\text{wrong}}$

1.$\color{Red}{   n+1 =   \text{prime numbers and twice of prime numbers 
}   }.$

2.$\color{Red}{ n+1= 4, 9, 2, 8 } .$

for all the other cases 
the assertion is 
$\color{Blue}{\text{true}}$ .

---

---

---

---

---

---

$\color{Red}{\text{Remark(V)}}$ : 
Let $p$ to be an odd prime number; 
then we have: 
$p^2 \color{Red}{\nmid} (2p-1)! \ \ . $

---

For example let $p$ to be an odd prime number; 
and let's define: 
$$n:=2p-1 
\ \ \ 
\text{and} 
\ \ \ 
x:=1 
\ \ \ 
\text{and} 
\ \ \ 
y:=p-1.$$

Notice that we have: $n=xy+x+y$

---

We calaim that $(2p)^2 \color{Red}{\nmid} (2p-1)!$.

[ 
**Suppose on contrary** 
that $(2p)^2 \mid (2p-1)!$ , 
on the otherhand notice that 
$p^2 \mid (2p)^2$. 
So we must have 
$p^2 \mid (2p-1)!$ 
; 
which has an obvious contradiction 
with the above $\color{Red}{\text{Remark(V)}}$. 
]

Comment: @Pickle , See the $\color{Green}{\text{Remark(Iv)}}$.

Comment: This comment is unreadable. Please fix the formatting otherwise you cannot expect me to read it.